# Using write.csv() function in R but it doesn't actually save it to my C:

Tags: r, csv

I'm a newbie and have searched Stack, the internet, everywhere I can think of.. But I cannot figure out why when I use write.csv() in R it doesn't actually save it as a csv file on my computer. All I want is to get a .csv file of my work from RStudio to Tableau and I've spent a week trying to figure it out. Many of the answers I have read use too much coding "lingo" and I cannot translate it because I'm just a beginner. Would be so so thankful for any help.
Here is the code I'm using:

""write.csv(daily_steps2,"C:\daily_steps2.csv", row.names = TRUE)""

I put the double quotes around the code because it seems like that's what I'm supposed to do here? IDK, but I don't have those when I run the function. There is no error when I run this, it just doesn't show up as a .csv on my computer. It runs but actually does nothing. Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: That line with single backslash without a control character like `\n` should actually error out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the simplest way would be to save the file to the same folder that rstudio is running in, and use the rstudio gui.  It should be write.csv(daily_steps, "./daily_steps.csv") (no quotes around the function), and then on the tab in the bottom right of rstudio, you can select files, and it should be there.  Then you can use the graphic user interface to move it to your desktop in a way analogous to what you would do in MS word.

Comment: THANK YOU for mentioning that it was saving in the files tab in the lower right. I was looking on my actual file folders, like my desktop or wherever i was trying to save it. I really appreciate you taking the time to answer.

Comment: They are actually the same place, just different views of it.  you should be able to match up the folder names and find the same place in the file explorer

Comment: Thanks for the info - I honestly don't have it on my desktop though. I searched in file explorer and tried it with various locations on my computer several times. So frustrating when I'm apparently doing something right but it just doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix is to use double slashes or forward slash for Windows paths. (Also, since `row.names=TRUE` is the default, there is no need to specify)

```r
write.csv(daily_steps2, "C:\\daily_steps2.csv")

write.csv(daily_steps2, "C:/daily_steps2.csv")
```

However, consider the OS-agnostic `file.path()` and avoid issues of folder separators in file paths including forward slash (used on Unix systems like Mac and Linux) or backslash (used on Windows systems).

```r
write.csv(daily_steps2, file.path("C:", "daily_steps2.csv"))
```

Another benefit is that because of this functional form to path expression, you can pass dynamic file or folder names without `paste`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I also tried it with double slashes and it wouldn't save on my actual computer. Your last sentence confuses me a little bit: I do not know what functional form to path expression" or "pass dynamic file names without paste" mean because I am just a beginner.

Comment: Hmmmm....what error if any did you receive with double back slashes? Even with permission issues, you should receive a message. Are you really trying on C drive or a different letter drive? Did `file.path` as recommended here work? Last sentence may be for future readers.

Comment: This is what I used: write.csv(daily_steps2,"C:\\test.csv", row.names = TRUE)

Comment: OMG I hit enter too soon and it posted..
This is what I used: write.csv(daily_steps2,"C:\\test.csv", row.names = TRUE)
I looked on my C drive, searched my whole computer. There was no error message and it did save the file in the lower right quadrant of my RStudio.
I just tried the file.path and this is the error:

write.csv(daily_steps2, file.path("C:", "test.csv"))
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'C:/test.csv': No such file or directory

Comment: I believe this is a permissions issue. You cannot save to that directory. Try your user's Documents folder (e.g., `file.path("C:", "Users", "jhakes", "Documents", "test.csv")`).

Comment: Hi Parfait, It still didn't save to my computer. Thanks for your help, I guess I'll just work around it because there's obviously a disconnect somewhere (on my end: either I just don't get it - highly probable - or there is something technical wrong) and I won't be able to figure that out with my level of expertise. I'll just copy and paste the script to a document or something and call it a day.